# uib-tabset along with a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal in which i want to show uib-tabset on like 75% of the left side of the form and 25% on the right side of the form.

Below is the structure of the code snippet:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 85%;top: 30px;min-width:600px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="closeVideo()" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <div class="container" style="width: 100%">
                    <uib-tabset active="active" style="width: 80%">
                    // blah blah blah
                    </uib-tabset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want the container to occupy 80% of the space in the modal which is done by altering the width in the style attr. I have another form now which i want it to float on right and occupy 20% of the form. How should i do this ?